# How to find largest value from multiple ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

i have three ArrayList of Integers type, i want to find largest integer value from those ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Integer> data1 = new ArrayList<>();
data1.add(20);
data1.add(30);
data1.add(40);
data1.add(51);
data1.add(71);
data1.add(212);
data1.add(203);
ArrayList<Integer> data2 = new ArrayList<>();
data2.add(56);
data2.add(67);
data2.add(267);
data2.add(257);
data2.add(367);
data2.add(363);
data2.add(233);
ArrayList<Integer> data3 = new ArrayList<>();
data3.add(36);
data3.add(12);
data3.add(366);
data3.add(53);
data3.add(124);
data3.add(256);
data3.add(203);

System.out.println("Largest Value = ");
```

is there any simplest way to find largest value from multiple arraylist?
Thanks !

Comment: I would not directly go into the code. What you can do is, add all the elements from the three arrayLists to a single arrayList. Then do a sort on this arrayList in reverse order. And the first element of it will be you result. You can try to convert this logic to your code I hope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a really simple one, that doesn't require any re-structuring of the data, and doesn't use streams. Not that there's anything wrong with using streams, but just to offer an alternative solution.

```
Integer maxValue = Math.max(Collections.max(data1), Math.max(Collections.max(data2), Collections.max(data3)));
```

Comment: Nice answer, but combining collections does not necessarily mean moving things around +1

Comment: That's an interesting thought. In my head I'd imagined the data to be moved to be consecutive in memory, but I guess that's array thinking :P

Answer (score 4):

Combine the last two lists into the first one, and then use `Collections.max()`:

```
data1.addAll(data2);
data1.addAll(data3);
Integer maxValue = Collections.max(data1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>(data1);
newList.addAll(data2);
newList.addAll(data3);
Collestions.sort(newList);
Collections.reverse(newList);
System.out.println("max: " + newList.get(0));
```

or

```
Integer max(Integer element, List<Integer> list) {
  Integer result = element;
  for (Integer num : list) {
    if (num > result) {
      result = num;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Using `max` method:

```
Integer result = max(data1.get(0), data1);
result = max(result, data2);
result = max(result, data3);
System.out.println("max: " + result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [java.util.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

```
Integer maxValue = Stream.of(data1, data2, data3)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .max(Integer::compare)
    .get();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like streams & co:

```
import package java.util.stream.Stream;

[...]

int max = Stream.of(data1.stream(), data2.stream(), data3.stream())
    .flatMap(i -> i)
    .mapToInt(i -> i)
    .max()
    .getAsInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another streaming example, not flat-mapping to a single stream

```
    Integer max = Stream.of(data1, data2, data3)
        .map(list -> list.stream().max(Integer::compare).get())
        .max(Integer::compare).get();
```